# How to call a method in .cs file in App_Code folder in aspx.cs file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

**My .cs file in App_Code folder**

```
namespace OnlineShoppingSite.App_Code
{
    public class Product
    {
        public Product(string prodID, string prodName, string prodDesc,
                       decimal unitPrice, string prodImage, string prodImage2, string prodDetails, string prodMeasurement, string prodCare)
        public Product getProduct(string prodID)
        {
        }
}
```

**My .aspx.cs file**

```
using OnlineShoppingSite.App_Code;
namespace OnlineShoppingSite
{
    public partial class ProductDetails : BasePage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

How do I retrieve the getProduct method in the .aspx.cs file? I added in using "OnlineShoppingSite.App_Code;" at the top of the file but it shows me this error
'App_Code' does  not exist in your namespace 'OnlineShoppingSite'(are you missing an online assembly reference?) "

Comment: `var product = new Product(.... your params); then product.GetProduct(prodId)` ??

Comment: You might also need a `using OnlineShoppingSite.App_Code;` at the top of the aspx.cs file, to add the namespace. There's nothing special about code in the App_Code folder. It's just classes and methods. If you know the basics of C# then you should already know what to do. It's unclear exactly what the problem is. Have you tried something and encountered a more specific issue that you want to ask about?

Comment: i tried both the methods. For the second method, I have got this error " 

'App_Code' does not exist in your namespace 'OnlineShoppingSite'(are you missing an online assembly reference?) "

Answer (score 0):

Your first constructor is missing braces.

```
public Product(string prodID, string prodName, string prodDesc,
    decimal unitPrice, string prodImage, string prodImage2, string prodDetails, 
    string prodMeasurement, string prodCare)
{
}
```

What you could do is remove `.App_Code` from the namespace name, and remove the namespace block from the code-behind page.

```
namespace OnlineShoppingSite
{
    public class Product
    {
        public Product(string prodID, string prodName, string prodDesc, ...)
        {
        }

        public Product getProduct(string prodID)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

.aspx.cs file

```
using OnlineShoppingSite;

public partial class ProductDetails : BasePage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```